# OpenXML SDK C# - Shared Formula corrupts my Excel file

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, openxml-powertools

I am trying to insert a Shared Formula into an existing Excel sheet. every time I open the finished Excel, it shows me an error and fixes the Excel. I have the code from OpenXML Productivity Tools. All other formulas work without problems ...

```
var cellFormula141 = new CellFormula
{
    FormulaType = CellFormulaValues.Shared,
    Reference = $"J{rowIndex}",
    SharedIndex = 0U,
    Text = $"CONCATENATE(MONTH(I{rowIndex}),\"/\",YEAR(I{rowIndex}))"
};

var cellValue215 = new CellValue
{
    Text = ""
};

cell372.Append(cellFormula141);
cell372.Append(cellValue215);
```

Every time I open the excel it is fixed and the formula is gone.

Answer (score 0):

pipe,

I’m also still struggling with open xml but maybe this will help.
I’m not sure if you differentiate correctly between source cell and shared cell.

**Compare the Properties of**

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell
```

**source cell:**

```
CellFormula.Text == "A1+B1"
CellFormula.FormulaType.Value == "Shared"
CellFormula.Reference == "A2:A9"
CellRefrence == "A2"
```

**shared cell:**

```
CellFormula.Text == ""
CellFormula.FormulaType.Value == "Shared"
CellFormula.Reference == null
CellRefrence == "A3"
```

You could also build a xlsx-File with this kind of formula and compare differences between these cells.

Also: it is always important to append cells from right to left to your DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row. Otherwise your xml file needs to be repaired.